# OutputFile is deprecated in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle

I'm trying to generate the apk release. However, when i run the command ./gradlew bundlerelease it gives the error

Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.

I have tried deleting the drawable dir at android/app/main/src/res but it still didn't work. I traced it to the android/app/build.gradle file where it says OuputFile is deprecated. Please how do I refactor this?

App/build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "task"
    minSdk 22
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
ndkVersion '21.4.7075529'
```

}

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
implementation 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20'
implementation 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
apply plugin: "de.undercouch.download"
```

Android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


import com.android.build.OutputFile  //OutputFile is deprecated
...
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described 
here:
        // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
        // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)  //OutputFile is deprecated
```